# How can I add external libraries in jdk-11?

Tags: java, servlets, java-11, openjdk-11

I want to compile a java code that using servlet with javac command. So I need to add servlet-api.jar into jdk-11 to compile it.

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq What kind of attitude is this? He is not asking for code. He simply asked how to compile a java program with an external library. I would recommend to to read the https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @PeterLustig i didn't disrespect the question and I just simply asked the effort he did to resolve issue. If you read question, it's more a like asking for solution but it can be found easily after some search or otherwise show some effort. I would say to the questionnaire to read this: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @PeterLustig I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of stackoverflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit :)

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq `stackoverflow is not a free code writing service` yeah this sounds like a friendly comment to me lol. The link was for you and my language is perfectly fine. I just asked a quesiton to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to add the servlet-api.jar into the jdk. You want to add the .jar to your classpath.

You can try something like:

```
javac -cp servlet-api.jar MainClass
```

You need to specify the full path to you .jar and to your class which contains the `main()` method